# How do I compare the product dates to today's date and create a new column where it indicates whether they have expired or not?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

| RM | RACK | CROP | Towers | Transplant date | harvest | harvest date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GR1 | R1a | LLQ | 7 | 2021-4-03 | 21 | 2021-4-24 |

O: overdue
H: need to clear by today
N: not due yet

Today's date: 2021-04-29
This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import date

df = pd.read_csv("CGA Towers Spatial.csv")

growth = {'LLQ': 21, 'AZK': 24, 'JER': 21, 'MUS': 35, 'CHA': 28, 'SOR': 28, 'ICE': 35, 'TMD': 21}
df['HARVEST'] = df['CROP'].apply(lambda x:growth[x])
df['HARVEST DATE'] = df['TRANSPLANT DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TRANSPLANT DATE'])
df['HARVEST DATE'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['TRANSPLANT DATE'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=x['HARVEST']), 1)
df.to_csv('CGA Towers Spatial.csv',index=False)
df.set_index('RM', inplace=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 258)

current_date = time.strptime(pd.to_datetime(date.today()).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y')

for index in df.index:
    date_check = time.strptime(pd.to_datetime(df.loc[index, 'HARVEST DATE']).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y')
    if current_date >= date_check:
        df.loc[index, 'check'] = 'H'
print(df)
```

This is the error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kohjiayu/Desktop/PycharmProjects/towers/tower_add_harvest.py", line 21, in 
date_check = time.strptime(pd.to_datetime(df.loc[index, 'HARVEST DATE']).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y')
File "/Users/kohjiayu/.conda/envs/towers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5465, in **getattr**
return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

I would like to add a new column which indicates whether my product has expired/needs to be cleared/not yet but i have no idea how to get the csv mod to read these dates and add indications. Ive tried but there is error. Pls help, I'm new to python.

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted, If you haven't attempted anything yet, start by searching how to read a csv into a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import time

df = pd.read_csv(file)

df.loc[(df['manufacture date'] == time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), 'expired/ due today/ not yet'] = 'H'
df.loc[(df['manufacture date'] < time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),'expired/ due today/ not yet'] = 'O'
df.loc[(df['manufacture date'] > time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),'expired/ due today/ not yet'] = 'N'
```